# Network wiring template for Visio

Tags: cable, switch

Anyone come across a good template/symbol pack for Visio for doing network wiring, patching, switch topologies, etc.?  Everything in Visio for networking is 3D, and isn't really conducive to cabling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco has some good ones. http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac50/ac47/2.html They do look 3Dish though, but maybe you'll find some uses for them.

Comment: I've used these they are pretty nice

Answer (score 1):

I know it's hokey looking, but I just drew boxes for the switches, and used the most basic connectors for wiring. It's ugly looking, but it's very easy to read and update.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't looked there yet, try VisioCafe ( http://www.visiocafe.com/ )

There are many vendor stencil packs and/or links to a vendor's actual stencil to download and you may find some stencils you like.

"Netzoom" / altimatech ( http://www.altimatech.com/ ) has some free (and for-pay) stencil packs including Siemons network stencils that some members of our network team used to be after our boss to purchase.